# Difference between inline void and void inline in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I just need to know what's the difference between `inline void` and `void inline` in C/C++ compiler.

Comment: No semantic difference.

Comment: c and c++ are separate languages, please don't tag both

Comment: No difference at all

Answer (score 2):

There's no semantic difference. In C's grammar, `inline` is a "function-specifier".

If you look at the [definition of a declaration](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7):

```
      declaration:
             declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
             static_assert-declaration
      declaration-specifiers:
             storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
             type-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
             type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt
             function-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
             alignment-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
      init-declarator-list:
              init-declarator
              init-declarator-list , init-declarator
      init-declarator:
              declarator
              declarator = initializer
```

you'll see that function-specifiers in a declaration (which for functions, is part of definitions too) can be arbitrarily permuted with storage-class specifiers (e.g., `static`), type-specifiers (e.g., `int`, `long`, `signed`, `unsigned`), type qualifiers (`const`, `volatile`, `restrict`) and alignment specifiers (`_Alignas(type_name)` or `_Alignas(constant_expression)`).

Answer (score 1):

There are no differences, but is suggested to use `inline void`.

Note that `inline` functions are supported in C++ and C99 though with different semantics.